# XUL-based simple text editor? (to benefit from Rikaichan when writing text files)

Tags: firefox, japanese

I love Firefox's Rikaichan extension, it shows the meaning of Japanese kanjis when hovering the mouse over them.

I am writing a lot of text in Japanese, so to benefit from Rikaichan I edit in a HTML-textarea page I created locally. I open this page in a Firefox tab when I want to write a text. The problem is that the risks of loosing the text is high.

A better alternative would be a XUL-based (Firefox extension?) Notepad-like simple text editor.

Thunderbird is too heavy. Gmail's Compose window is not convenient and inserts undesirable carriage returns.

([related](http://forum.koohii.com/viewtopic.php?id=2656))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could use [Cloud9](http://cloud9ide.com/). However, since you edit the files on a local html area, I would recommend using [Textarea Cache](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5761/) extension. It will avoid losing what you have typed in any textarea fields.

Comment: Thanks! I installed the Textarea Cache extension and will check it.

Comment: Finally using an HTML area and Textarea cache.

Comment: Glad to read it solved your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You may use a tiddlywiki. It is an HTML file with embedded javascript that allows modifications and stores them into itself. 
Or, if you prefer cloud solution - Google Docs. It also has an autosave feature.

Comment: +1 TiddlyWiki looks very promising, I tried it a bit and it seems to work, I will check a bit more how it saves things. I was afraid Google Docs would not be adapted for simple text (ex: try to bulletize my text-based lists) but it seems to behave correctly!